# How can I use BOOTSTRAP in WORDPRESS?

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap-4

I'm new to WORDPRESS is it possible to use or import bootstrap in my custom plugin?
If not is there any kind of like bootstrap that I can use in designing my plugin?

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the file **header.php** of the theme that you are using, in the editor this file may be described as "**Theme Header**". You need to link it to bootstrap:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

This is the link they currently provide, though you can copy this directly from their webpage: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction

Notice that you are making changes to your theme file, so if the theme is updated your added code might be removed. To solve this you should use a child theme, which allows you to make changes that aren't overridden by theme updates.

If you want to add bootstrap using the built-in editor I recommend you use one tutorial by steps, like this one: https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/wordpress/how-to-use-bootstrap-in-wordpress/

Once bootstrap is installed you should be able to use it as usual.

Comment: hello pauescofet thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```html
function prefix_theme_name_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'slider', 'cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'prefix_theme_name_styles' );

you can use the code for adding bootstrap in your plugin. Aso you can download the bootstarap and add it your plugin folder then enqueue it 

function add_my_stylesheet() 
{
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', plugins_url( '/css/bootstrap.css', __FILE__ ) );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_stylesheet');
```

Comment: hello Shagor Ahmed thanks.